# Use of article in referring to carboxylic acids in a generic sense

Tags: definite-articles, indefinite-articles

Premises: Carboxylic acids are a class of organic acids. Both acetic acid and lauric acid are examples of carboxylic acids.

In example 1, 10 g of acetic acid was added to the solution. In example 2, by contrast, 0.1 g of lauric acid was added.

> The *amount of carboxylic acid* added is much greater in example 1 than in example 2.
>
> A smaller *amount of carboxylic acid* was used in example 2 than in example 1.

The term "carboxylic acid" is supposed to be a countable noun because it can refer to many different kinds of acids and the usage above bothers me.  Should there be an indefinite article before "carboxylic acid"?  In other words, should the italicized parts read "amount of a carboxylic acid"?

Thank you.

Comment: 'Carboxylic acid', and more simply 'acid', have both count and non-count usages, as indicated at [M-W Learner's Dictionary](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/acid). The examples are fine. Compare 'Two coffees, please' / 'The amount of coffee drunk'.

Comment: Since you are distinguishing between one acid and another, though both carboxylic, adding _a_ carboxylic acid helps the clarity. Put another way, it looks like you are not pouring carboxylic acid in, but one carboxylic acid in one example and one other in the other example.

Comment: Surely you mean Definite article! The indefinite article would never be used. Or perhaps you are not a native English speaker?

Comment: OK, I didn't read it properly on the phone.

Answer (score 1):

I can only speak from experience as a native English speaker in writing and refereeing biochemical research papers for publication in a variety of journals over many years.

I would say that the form with **no article**:

> A smaller amount of *carboxylic acid* was used in example 2 than in example 1.

is **correct** both grammatically and in conveying your meaning if, as you state, you have already explained that you are comparing different carboxylic acids and what they are.

I would say that the form with the **definite article**:

> A smaller amount of *the carboxylic acid* was used in example 2 than in example 1.

is also **correct** grammatically and perhaps emphasizes slightly the fact that each is a different carboxylic acid. For this reason it might be preferred.

I would say that the form with the **indefinite article**:

> A smaller amount of *a carboxylic acid* was used in example 2 than in example 1.

is correct grammatically on its own, but **incorrect** in this context because you have already stated what the two carboxylic acids are — hence you need the definite rather than the indefinite article. To me using the indefinite article throws doubt on the previously stated identities.

If you had not stated what the two carboxylic acids were — for example if you were writing a problem question for a student exam in which the students had to deduce the identity of the carboxylic acids — then the indefinite article would be both necessary and correct.